# Customer login dropdown menu clipped in OpenCart on multiple stores

Tags: jquery, html, css, opencart, opencart2.x

This issue is only when you have multiple stores configured in OpenCart. On the admin side, when you filter on a customer name and the search results in only one customer in the list, the "Login into Store" dropdown menu is clipped (see first image below) on a desktop browser but a scrollbar is added so you can click the second store link by scrolling.

But on mobile (see second image below) there is no scrollbar so you cannot login to either store because it is not visible. I thought it just may be a z-index issue but that isn't the case. Anyone have thoughts on how to correct this?

[image: dropdown menu clipped with multiple stores configured in OpenCart]

[image]

[image: dropdown menu CSS code]

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I run into similar situations, I've always solved by something like:

```
padding-bottom: 20px;
```

or try

```
position: relative;
```

In your element inspector, do you have checkmarks where you can live-disable the class? I'm not sure what browser you're using, but on Firefox, if I hover to the left of the class I want to test, By un-checking the checkbox, it temporarily disables it so you can see where the culprit is.

If you have Firefox Developer Edition, switch the Responsive Mode on and inspect the affected elements that way, too.